# Healthkit StepData IoS

Tags: c#, ios, xamarin, xamarin.ios, healthkit

I am trying to access step data from 1 year back in healthkit on iOS using xamarin C#, yet I can't get the method and syntax right. All I want is to get an array of steps or a string or something useable.

I've been following the guide and document on Xamarin, posting link if anyone want to read.

Fixed the code to compile, yet still get no data. It seems Hk quantity is unable to convert the data and quantity remains null.

```
query.InitialResultsHandler = (query2, results, error) =>
        {
            if (error != null)
            {
                Debug.WriteLine("*** An error occurred while calculating the statistics: %@ ***", error.LocalizedDescription);
            }
            else
            {
                NSDate startDate = NSDate.Now.AddSeconds(TimeSpan.FromDays(-365).TotalSeconds);
                NSDate endDate = NSDate.Now.AddSeconds(TimeSpan.FromDays(1).TotalSeconds);
                results.EnumerateStatistics(startDate, endDate, handler: ((result, stop) =>
                {

                    HKQuantity quantity = result.SumQuantity();
                    if (quantity != null)
                    {
                        NSDate date = result.StartDate;
                        double value = quantity.GetDoubleValue(HKUnit.Count);
                        Debug.WriteLine(date, value.ToString());
                    }
                }));
            }

        };
        healthKitStore.ExecuteQuery(query);
        Debug.WriteLine(query);
    }
```

Comment: `result` is null too?

Comment: Result is not null, result contains 4 values. So seems to be good. Seems like the conversion from quantity to result casting doesn't work.

Comment: In the debugger, result has the value in the base, retaincountvalue has in the static members the value of maxium "4294967295" minium = 0 and size 4. I'm assuming these are the values I want to acess. Seems to fit the amount of values i've entered manually into Healthkit, except it's a bit larger than expected.

Comment: It seems I get this error when trying to convert according to the debugger  "= Unable to cast object of type 'System.RuntimeType' to type 'Mono.Debugger.Soft.TypeMirror'." This is when hovering over the Hkquality quality identifier